# React function not rerendering with UseEffect and setting state combo

Tags: react-hooks, react-functional-component, prism-react-renderer

Utilising UseEffect react function and trying to call an API once then render the information, but render post the data being received is not being triggered despite having a call to setState within the fetchdata function call within useEffect.
Would appreciate any assistance on how to resolve this?

Code Snippet below

```
const Function= () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [error, setError] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`URL`);
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    }
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);

if (error) {
  return <div>An error occurred: {error.message}</div>;
           }
if (!data) {    
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
           }
   return (
     {data&& (
              data?.map((item) => (<Display Logic>)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seemed there was some old local dependencies, so by running with --force and redownloading them has resolved the issue